# Filter multiple columns with non blanks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm attempting to filter columns D, E, G, H, I all at the same time. I need to
display rows that have values and filter off blanks in all the columns simultaneously. 
Does anybody know if it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Did you try doing it manually?  If that works then try recording a macro while doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a straightforward task, but can be achieved if you make a new column typing in the formula:

`IF(OR(ISBLANK(D2:I2)),1,0)` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now, you can filter this column and all the rows having even a single blank entry would be filtered.

Also, if you want to filter only when all entries are blank in these columns, you can replace the `OR` with `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works in a lot of situations. However sometimes there are non-printed characters hidden in the cell (I have found this when importing CSV data). In this scenario you need to check that the total length of the data in all the cells is greater than 0.

```
IF(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(D2:I2)),1,0)
```

Using `SUMPRODUCT` is an alternative to `SUM` function and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>